# how to cchange os of app in xcode from 4.3 to 4.0 to work on ipad

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I have built app on os 4.3 and my device has 4.2.1 so how can set in xcode 4.0 so that it may run on my device i am using xcode 3.2.6 and ios sdk 4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the iOS Deployment Target (in the build Target settings) to the oldest SDK you want the app to be compatible with.

Comment: i have done like that but again when i build it says app runs on 4.3

Comment: if you set the deployment target to 4.3 then it will not run on 4.2.1... can you set the deployment target to 4.2?

Comment: i have set deployment target to 4.0

Comment: hmmm... not sure then.  My only idea would be to make sure that you're talking about the deployment target and not the base sdk (which can be a more recent sdk than the deployment target).

Comment: no i am setting in deployment target setting again there show 4.0 but when i build and archive app and test it don't runs